# Avoid type safety warning after deserializing recursive Map<String,Object> with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am getting from a REST API a recursive dictionnary that I import in Java as a `Map<String,Object>` using Jackson with the following code

```
  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECTMAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private static  final MapType GENERICMAPTYPE = OBJECTMAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
            Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
...

  Map<String, Object> response =  OBJECTMAPPER.readValue(result.getBody(),GENERICMAPTYPE);
```

I then try to do down in the tree for some attributes, with code like

```
   if (response.get("infos") instanceof Map<?,?>)
            Map<String, Object> infos = (Map<String, Object>) response.get("infos");
```

I get a type safety warning on the cast to Map. Perfectly understandable.
Is there a betterway than adding the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` here to tell the compiler everything will work fine?

Comment: Why use such a structure? Jackson has `JsonNode`, you know...

Comment: JsonNode is the right way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per fge's comment, the jackson JsonNode type is the right way to go.

```
JsonNode responseAsTree = OBJECTMAPPER.readTree(responseAsString);
```

The JsonNode has all methods necessary to traverse the tree in an easy way. See [Faster XML Tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Tree_Model_Example)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `response` is a `Map<String, Object>`.
You are calling `response.get("infos")`. From the supplied generics, this returns `Object`, which has to be cast to Map and this is why you get a warning.

What you can do is to not use a `Map<String, Object>`, but define classes, that represent the structure of your response JSON.

Something like

```
public class Response {

    private Infos infos;

}

public class Infos {

     private int foo;
     private String bar;
}
```

Then, you can use Jackson to parse the response into this class structure and access all properties via getters / setters, ensuring that your code is type-safe.